# Elasticsearch Range Query with wildcard in field name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple range query:

```
{
"query": {
    "range": {
        "unified_source.step_11.sizeIncome":  {
             "gte" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

}

But I need to apply this query to all nested objects, like this:

```
{
"query": {
    "range": {
        "unified_source.*.sizeIncome":  {
             "gte" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

}

This returns no hits.

Is that possible to use some wildcard there?

Can I 'combine' that query with Query String Query somehow? (In Query String wildcard can be used to search "within" specific inner elements of the document).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do [range queries in a query_string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "unified_source.*.sizeIncome:>=10"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This query looks well, but it leads to jvm heap usage keeps increasing slowly and there is no response for a long time. No responce at all.  Strange, beacause I have only 100 documents within that index.

Comment: Well, wildcards are rarely a good idea when it comes to performance. but indeed, if you only have 100 documents, that's weird