# How to use Eleasticsearch query_string wildcards for the the key

Tags: elasticsearch

inside of a document that I indexed in Elasticsearch contains an array, it looks like the following.

```
 "creditScoreTenantResults.123456789X.creditScore": [
    73.72
  ],
  "creditTenants.address.country.keyword": [
     "country1"
  ],
  "creditScoreTenantResults.123456789X.personalId.keyword": [
     "123456789X"
  ],
  "creditUuid.keyword": [
     "9d7ba281-2602-42f7-aae7-40c802ede21c"
  ],
```

and I implemented the following query.

```
POST http://localhost:56677/csm/_search?pretty
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "creditScoreTenantResults.123456789X.creditScore :>10"
       }
    },
    "fields": ["*"]
}
```

which works perfectly but actually the question I like to ask, actually is more like 'give me all credit scores bigger then 10', so I converted the query string to 'creditScoreTenantResults.*.creditScore :>10' while I read in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763485/elasticsearch-range-query-with-wildcard-in-field-name) that it should work.

Unfortunately Elasticsearch reporting a Parsing Exception, complaining with the wildcard version it can recognise ':' from ':>10', is the post I mentioned correct? Is this query possible at all?

If yes, how can I formulate it?

PS. I am using Elasticsearch 7.16, may be it is not possible with it and I have to use ES8?

Thx for answers.

Comment: Did you try to escape the `*`, in case you're using Kibana Dev Tools? So, the field should be like this `creditScoreTenantResults.\*.creditScore`

Comment: I am not using the Kibana but the REST Client in IntelliJ, if I try to escape Exception transforms to the following '"reason": "Unrecognized character escape '*' (code 42)\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query_string query uses the [Lucene query language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), so your range condition should be like this:

```
creditScoreTenantResults.\*.creditScore:{10 TO *}
```

Comment: Yes, sir that works, but while I use IntelliJ REST Client and not Kibana, I have to escape it like the following '"query": "creditScoreTenantResults.\\*.creditScore: [10 TO *}"', thx for the answer Funny Stackoverflow escape this also it is double backward slashes "\\"